# When a variable is assigned the value of another variable. Is a copy of the object stored another place right away? Or later when a change is made?

Tags: python, variables, memory

I started studying robotics this week and watched a video-lecture about how variables are references to memoryadresses containing objects. The video was made by my professor. In the video, he explains how two variables will point towards the same object when the second variable is assigned the value off the first variable. [Here is an illustration he made](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qLL3o.png). The text is norwegian so here are some translations: navnerom = namespace, minnet = memory, objekter = objects, eksempelprogram = exampleprogram.

But I had asked GPT4.0 the same question earlier using the browserOP plugin.

###### The question I asked was:

> If a second variable is a assigned to a value which another variable already is assigned. Will this second variable point to the already existing object?

###### The answer I got was:

> In programming, whether a second variable points to the same object as the first variable when assigned its value depends on the type of data and the programming language in question. Here's a breakdown for some common scenarios:
>
> 1. Primitive Data Types (e.g., numbers, booleans, strings in some languages):
>
> When you assign the value of one variable to another variable, the value is copied. Both variables have the same value, but they are stored in separate memory locations. Changes to one variable do not affect the other.
>
> 2. Reference Data Types (e.g., objects, arrays, lists):
>
> When you assign the value of one variable (which is a reference to an object) to another variable, both variables now reference the same object in memory. Changes made through one variable will be reflected when accessed through the other variable.
> Here's a brief example in Python:

```
# For primitive data types
a = 5
b = a
b = 10
print(a)  # Outputs: 5
print(b)  # Outputs: 10

# For reference data types
list1 = [1, 2, 3]
list2 = list1
list2[0] = 99
print(list1)  # Outputs: [99, 2, 3]
print(list2)  # Outputs: [99, 2, 3]
```

> In the above example:
>
> - For the primitive data type (a and b), changing b did not affect a.
> - For the reference data type (list1 and list2), changing an element in list2 also changed the corresponding element in list1 because they both reference the same list in memory.
>   However, it's important to note that the behavior can vary based on the programming language and its specific implementation of data types.

I interpreted this as if python will create a copy of the object which **a** refers to, but place the copy at another memory address and let **b** point towards the new address. This makes it so **a** and **b** are pointing to two identical objects, but stored in different places. Meaning the objects can be altered independently from each other.

I tested this by using pythons built-in id() function:

```
a = 5
b = a
print(id(a))
print(id(b))
a += 1
print(id(a))
```

And the output was:

```
140736222585768
140736222585768
140736222585800
```

This means my professor was right since the objects which a and b are referring to have the same memory address, right? But when altering the object through the variable a, the memory address changes. Does this mean a new object was created in the line `a += 1` and a's pointer was changed to this new object? But if this is the case, GPT4.0 gave the wrong answer.

Comment: Mandatory link to [Ned Batchelder](https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html)

Comment: Stop asking ChatGPT questions like this.

Comment: It's giving you a generic answer, btw. It is not applicable to Python. For example, python **doesn't have primitive types, everything is an object**. Your professor is correct.

Comment: "I interpreted this as if python will create a copy of the object which a refers to, but place the copy at another memory address and let b point towards the new address" that isn't what happens in Python

Comment: `a += 1` does not operate on `a` in-place; it is simply a short-hand version for `a = a + 1`; the right-hand side first defines the object and the left-hand side then assigns a name to it.  It is appropriate to think of the name`a` as a label which can be attached to an object and moved to another.